# How to change 'eval' output format in a document. (remove the ##)

Tags: r-markdown

When R-Markdown output a chunk result, it insert a ## before the result.

I would like to know how could I change the default result format, specially how to change the double hashtag for another symbol (to not make beginners confused with the code comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this within a setup chunk, e.g.

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = "#>")
```
````

will prefix `#>` instead of `##`.